# prove the continuity of $T_\phi f=\int_0^1 f(x)\phi(x) \,dx\\$

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $\phi\in C[0,1]$ and let $T_\phi~:C[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, defined as $T_\phi f=\int_0^1 f(x)\phi(x) \,dx\\$. How can i prove that it's a continuous operator?

Comment: What do you know about continuous functions on a bounded set?

Comment: @Ariel : Didn't you ask an almost identical question that was answered?

Comment: @Gary. ah that's why this question seemed so familiar to me....

Comment: it's the same way?

Comment: @Nameless: and I was dumb enough to answer it.

Comment: @Gary.:i'm the dumb here, excuse me.

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo: Sorry, I did not mean to imply that, we all make mistakes. Feel free to ask any followup question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $\phi .f(x)$ is a continuous function, as a product of continuous functions. Since it is defined on a compact set, it takes on a maximum $M$, then $T_{\phi} \leq \int_0^1 Mdx =M(1-0)=M$

Then $T_{\phi}$ is a bounded linear operator, and so it is continuous.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, to make this more rigorous ( I took shortcuts ) we need to show that, for any f in the unit ball in $C[0,1]$ ( i.e., $Sup f =1 $ ), we must have a constant $M$ so that $|T_{\phi}f| \leq M||f||_{\infty}=M  $ (Since $f$ is in the unit ball ). The result then follows by the continuity of $f . \phi$ and the compactness of $[0,1]$ ; $|T_{\phi}| \leq ||\phi(x)||_{\infty}=Max_{x \in [0,1]} \phi(x)$.

Comment: When you wrote $\phi f(x)$, you mean $\phi(x).f(x)$, right?

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo: Yes, sorry, let me rewrite it more clearly.

Comment: This is just wrong. It should say that for any $f \in C[0,1]$, we have that $$|T_{\phi} f| \leq \int_0^1 \|\phi\|_{\infty} |f| dx \leq \|\phi\|_{\infty} \|f\|_{\infty}$$ Then $T_{\phi}$ is a bounded linear operator...

Comment: @Shalop: But I considered $f .\phi $ to be a single continuous function, and so it is bounded itself, by $M$.

Comment: @Gary: OK I edited my comment. But still, this is not the definition of a bounded linear operator. If $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces, then a linear map $f:X \to Y$ is said to be **bounded** iff there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $x \in X$, we have $\|Tx\|_Y \leq C\|x\|_X$. It doesn't look like that is what you showed.

Comment: @Shalop: OK, I took some shortcuts, let me rewrite.

Comment: @Shalop: I just edited. I need to go sleep now, but I will read any followups you may have tomorrow morning. I worked with f in the unit ball of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: It looks almost correct, but where did $k$ come from? All you need to say is that $f$ and $\phi$ are continuous on $[0,1]$, and hence bounded. Then, for any $x \in [0,1]$ we have $|f(x)\phi(x)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \|\phi\|_{\infty} $, and thus $$|T_{\phi}f| \leq \int_0^1 \big|\phi(x) f(x)\big| dx \leq \|\phi\|_{\infty} \|f\|_{\infty}$$ So $T_{\phi}$ is bounded, and this continuous. I think that this is basically what you're saying, right?

Comment: @Shalop, yes, that is correct, that is what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and in this case you can use Max instead of sup.

Comment: can i write this?: $\big|\int_0^1f(x)\phi(x)dx\big|\leq\int_0^1 \big| f(x) \phi(x) \big| dx\leq\int_0^1\sup\big| f(x)\phi(x)\big|dx\leq\int_0^1\sup\big|f(x)\big|\sup\big|\phi(x)\big|dx=\|\phi\|_{\infty} \|f\|_{\infty}$ con $x \in [0,1]$? it's correct?

Comment: Si, and notice that the last term is multiplied by $1-0=1$, these are the limits of integration.

Comment: @Shalop, I rewrote; I used $k$ by mistake.

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo: I did another edit to my post.

Comment: why $f$ has to be in the unit ball in $C[0,1]$?

Comment: It does not really have to be, but, by scaling properties of the norm, if a bound exists in the unit ball, then it exists everywhere in the space, just by multiplying by the right finite amount.